# What tailored OS distributions exist?

Tags: operating-systems

Is there already a specific tailored distribution for the Raspberry Pi?

My specific concern is about the lifetime of the SD card hosting the OS image.
Other distro addressed that like, for instance, *Voyage Linux* for the  [Alix board](http://pcengines.ch/alix.htm).

Comment: Related: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/33/are-there-any-non-linux-operating-systems-available?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the Raspberry Pi foundation have just (*this morning*) released their own distribution based on Debian.

It's called **[Raspbian](http://www.raspbian.org/)** and can be downloaded from their [main downloads page](http://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads).

This currently provides many advantages over other distributions as it as been built from the ground up for the Raspberry Pi. The major change is that the kernel and applications have been compiled with hard floating point support, which should improve speed quite drastically.

Comment: do you know if the developers have introduced some measures to limit the flash memory wear ?

Comment: I actually don't know, however you can take [some precautions yourself](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/169/how-can-i-extend-the-life-of-my-sd-card).

Comment: @AlexChamberlain Ridiculous. It's been rebuilt from scratch. Ubuntu is a build of Debian too but you wouldn't call them the same distro.

Comment: talking about raspbian, it is a pity that the user has to modify by hand the fstab and such.

Comment: @ziu I haven't actually used it yet, but I hear the user experience isn't so good for beginners...

Comment: @ziu Come on to chat - I don't understand